# Android Object with none of the Variables being added

Tags: android, arraylist, android-activity, addition

So i have this program which is basically a birthday reminder, and while i got most of it figured out, sadly when i want to add a friend instead of, for example, Rick J. 28, 1, 1980, it adds Friend[name=null, day=0, month=0, year=0]

Here is the code of where the adding is suppose to be done:

```
package com.example.birthdayminder;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private String name;
private boolean isOK = false;
GregorianCalendar gregCal;
Date date;
FriendList friendlist;
Friend friend;
EditText text;
CharSequence charSequence;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

}

public void checkFriend(){
    boolean duplicate = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<friendlist.getList().size(); i++){

        if(friendlist.getList().get(i).equals(friend) == true) {
            duplicate = true;
        }
    }
    if (name == null){
        charSequence = (CharSequence)"Name is empty!";
        Toast.makeText(this, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    }
    if(day == 0){
        charSequence = (CharSequence)"Not a valid day!";
        Toast.makeText(this, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
    }
    if(month == 0){
        charSequence = (CharSequence)"Not a valid month!";
        Toast.makeText(this, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
    }
    if(year == 0){
        charSequence = (CharSequence)"Not a valid year!";
        Toast.makeText(this, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
    }
    else if(duplicate==true){

        Toast.makeText(this, "This person already added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isOK =false;

    }
else {
        isOK=true;
    }
}


public void test(View view){
    Toast.makeText(this, "testing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void addClick(View view){
    text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.namefield);

    name = findViewById(R.id.namefield).toString();
    DatePicker datepick = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    day = datepick.getDayOfMonth();
    month = datepick.getMonth();
    year = datepick.getYear();
    friend = new Friend(name, day, month, year);
    friendlist = FriendList.getInstance();
    //the toast is to check if the object is added correctly
    Toast.makeText(this, friend.toString(), 4).show();
    checkFriend();
    if(isOK==true){
        friendlist.addFriend(new Friend(name, day, month, year));
        finish();
    }
}

//    This is the original code of the adding process, i attempted to re-do it to try and see if that could help me solve the problem
//    public void saveBirthday(View view){
//        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.namefield);
//
//        DatePicker datePick = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
//        name = findViewById(R.id.namefield).toString();
//        day = datePick.getDayOfMonth();
//        month = datePick.getMonth();
//        year = datePick.getYear();
//        fl = FriendList.getInstance();
//        friend = new Friend(name,day,month,year);
//        Toast.makeText(this, friend.toString(), 3).show();
//        checkFriend();
//        if(isOK==true){
//            fl.addFriend(friend);
//            finish();
//        }
//        
//
//    }
}
```

As for the list where the objects are supposed to be stored in, so they can be viewed in a listview:

```
package com.example.birthdayminder;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FriendList {

    ArrayList<Friend> friendList = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    private static FriendList instance = null;
    protected FriendList(){
        //prevents accidental creation of new instances
    }

    public static FriendList getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new FriendList();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    //Removes an entry and ads it to the end of the list
    public void moveToEnd(int friendNo){
        Friend chosenFriend =friendList.get(friendNo);
        friendList.remove(friendNo);
        friendList.add(chosenFriend);
    }

    public boolean addFriend(Friend friend){
        return friendList.add(friend);
    }

    public ArrayList getList(){
        return friendList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String name = friendList.get(0).getName();
        String bDay = Integer.toString(friendList.get(0).getMonth());
        String bMonth = Integer.toString(friendList.get(0).getMonth()+1);
        String bYear = Integer.toString(friendList.get(0).getYear());
        return name + "," + bDay + "," + bMonth + "," + bYear;
    }

    public void setList(ArrayList<Friend> friendArray) {
        this.friendList = friendArray;
    }



}
```

Overall i have 10 classes, 3 of which are different classes with sorting methods for the listview, i can post them all if the problem does not seem to be in any of the above classes

Comment: Try initializing your name, day, month and year variables to default values and check if a new friend is added with these default values instead of the desired ones. If so, the problem is somewhere in your addClick() method. An unrelated suggestion: Make your checkFriend() method return a boolean value instead of setting a global variable, ie. boolean checkFriend() { // if not dupliace return true, else return false }. In addClick(), you can then simply go if(checkFriend()) { friendlist.addFriend(...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do - especially the addClick (am not sure this onClick for DatePicker or any other button). Anyways, look at following two things:

1. Move initializing name and datePicker (make it class level) to onCreate.
2. Override toString() in Friend class as well, if not done.

Try this code:

```
public class AddActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private int year;
private int month;
private int day;
private String name;
private boolean isOK = false;
GregorianCalendar gregCal;
Date date;
FriendList friendlist;
Friend friend;
EditText text;
CharSequence charSequence;

DatePicker datepick;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namefield);


    datepick = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);


}

public void checkFriend() {
    boolean duplicate = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < friendlist.getList().size(); i++) {

        if (friendlist.getList().get(i).equals(friend) == true) {
            duplicate = true;
        }
    }
    if (name == null) {
        charSequence = (CharSequence) "Name is empty!";
        Toast.makeText(this, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    }
    if (day == 0) {
        charSequence = (CharSequence) "Not a valid day!";
        Toast.makeText(this, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    if (month == 0) {
        charSequence = (CharSequence) "Not a valid month!";
        Toast.makeText(this, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    if (year == 0) {
        charSequence = (CharSequence) "Not a valid year!";
        Toast.makeText(this, charSequence, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    } else if (duplicate == true) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "This person already added",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isOK = false;

    } else {
        isOK = true;
    }
}

public void test(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "testing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void addClick(View view) {

    name = text.getText().toString();
    day = datepick.getDayOfMonth();
    month = datepick.getMonth();
    year = datepick.getYear();
    friend = new Friend(name, day, month, year);
    friendlist = FriendList.getInstance();
    // the toast is to check if the object is added correctly
    Toast.makeText(this, friend.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    checkFriend();
    if (isOK == true) {
        friendlist.addFriend(new Friend(name, day, month, year));
        finish();
    }
}

// This is the original code of the adding process, i attempted to re-do it
// to try and see if that could help me solve the problem
// public void saveBirthday(View view){
// text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.namefield);
//
// DatePicker datePick = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
// name = findViewById(R.id.namefield).toString();
// day = datePick.getDayOfMonth();
// month = datePick.getMonth();
// year = datePick.getYear();
// fl = FriendList.getInstance();
// friend = new Friend(name,day,month,year);
// Toast.makeText(this, friend.toString(), 3).show();
// checkFriend();
// if(isOK==true){
// fl.addFriend(friend);
// finish();
// }
//
//
// }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Araut, however annoyingly enough now the app just breaks down and the following log occurs:
04-19 01:15:21.460: E/AndroidRuntime(919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 01:15:21.460: E/AndroidRuntime(919): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Also if it would help i could add the other classes, but i do not know if it would maybe get too confusing?

Comment: Can you put the stack trace here?

Comment: Stack trace? care to explain?